# sortby doesn't work for angularjs after ajax request

Tags: angularjs, ajax

The ajax succesfuly pull out the data, but sort function seems not work properly.

alive: http://weijinglin.name/website/

```
        var ngApp = angular.module("webApp", ['xml'])
        .config(function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('xmlHttpInterceptor');
          })
        .controller("webCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.websites = [];
            $http.get("./data/web.json")
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.websites = response;

                for (i = 0; i < $scope.websites.length; i++) {
                    $scope.processWebsite($scope.websites[i], i);
                }
                //console.log(response);
            });
```

here is the function process the array

```
            $scope.processWebsite = function(website, index){
                //for ($scope.i = 0; $scope.i < $scope.websites.length; $scope.i++){
                    $http.get('../api/index.php/alexa?url=' + website.url)
                    .success(function(rsp) {
                        //$scope.websites[index].rank = rsp.data.POPULARITY.TEXT;
                        if (rsp.data && rsp.data.POPULARITY.TEXT) {
                            $scope.websites[index].rank = rsp.data.POPULARITY.TEXT;
                        } else {
                            $scope.websites[index].rank = 'NO DATA';
                        }
                        console.log();
                    });
                //}
            }
        });
```

I sort my data by using filter

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in websites | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
                <td>{{ x.cate }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.url }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.rank }}</td>
            </tr>
```

I use th as switch button to make the sort switchable

```
<th>
    <a href="#" ng-click="sortType='rank'; sortReverse= !sortReverse">Alex
        <i ng-show="sortType = 'rank' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
        <i ng-show="sortType = 'rank' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
</th>
```

Comment: I don't see you trying to sort anything in the provided code.

Comment: I update the code now, add the sort code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you can get all of your data successfully? Or could it be that you are doing the sorting before the get method has completed?

I think you should wrap your success (callback) in a `.then` function. Your sorting method will then be called async when the response is ready. I am assuming that `$scope.processWebsite` is sorting the response.

```
var myurl = '../api/index.php/alexa?url=' + website.url;
$http.get('myurl').then(
  function successCallback(response) { // on success
    if (rsp.data && rsp.data.POPULARITY.TEXT) {
      $scope.websites[index].rank = rsp.data.POPULARITY.TEXT;
    } else {
      $scope.websites[index].rank = 'NO DATA';
    }
  
    console.log();
  }, 
  function errorCallback(response) { // on error
    console.log();
  }
});
```

Angular's `http` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) states that:

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
> deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
> $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
> methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Note that this code has not been implemented or tested, but should provide you with an outline.

Comment: Yes, I got all data from ajax successfully. Did you try the demo on my website?